# How to format text with variable without quotes in SASS?

Tags: html, css, sass

In SASS, I have this

```
@mixin background_gradient($dir, $from, $to) {
    background: linear-gradient('to #{$dir}', $from, $to); // for IE10
}
```

Except in the browser in comes out to

```
browser: linear-gradient("to top", #ffffff, #ffffff)
```

but it needs to be

```
browser: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff, #ffffff)
```

without the quotes.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need to remove quotes from a string, you can use the [`unquote`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unquote-instance_method) function:

```
@mixin background_gradient($dir, $from, $to) {
    background: linear-gradient(unquote('to #{$dir}'), $from, $to);
}
```

Comment: apparently I just did `linear-gradient(to #{$dir}, $from, $to)` and that worked.